# Add function to firefox extension Javascript file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am actually working on a Firefox extension and I am trying to create objects containing both variables and methods in seperate Javascript files.
So I tried to declare the instance like this :

```
var options = {
  toto: null,

  ready: function() {
    console.log("Foo");
  }
};
```

And when I try to `console.log(options);` it only displays `{toto:null}`
And if I try to call the ready function it says ready is not declared.

What do I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you creating options object in a different file and ````console.log```` is in different file? It looks like options was somehow serialized and hence the function was removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Have tried the same code in chrome.
 There seems to be no issue with the Object creation.
```

Attaching the image for reference.

[image]

Object is displaying both 'todo' and 'ready' as its propery in console,and we can access them using 'Object.propertyName' in your case :

```
'options.todo' and 'options.ready()'
```

Comment: I am working on a firefox extension not on a website. So sorry but this does not help